# Oscillator value does not change in safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, web-audio-api

I am trying to make use of web audio api with NexusUI JS for dial/knobs?

In chrome the dial is changing the oscillator frequency but in safari its playing i think the default 440hz.

Can someone please direct me what am I missing or doing wrong ? It seems like I am in the right direction since I am getting output in chrome as safari is super strict some basic mistake is been overlooked by me.

Reason for using nexusUI: It was the most minimalist dial/knob I found. I only need a super basic knob. Toggle switch I can easily replace with a play / pause button.

Example of what I am trying to do. ([Same on codepen](https://codepen.io/Substance_D/pen/jOaLqZx))

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#2a2c2d";

var power = new Nexus.Toggle("#power", {
  state: false
});

Nexus.colors.accent = "#16e1ff";
Nexus.colors.fill = "#2a2c2d";
Nexus.colors.accent = "#16e1ff";

var dial = new Nexus.Dial("#dial");
dial.value = 0;
dial.min = 20;
dial.max = 6000;

dial.on("change", function (v) {
  knb1.frequency.value = v;
  console.log(v);
  return v;
});

window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();
var knb1 = context.createOscillator();

var knb1Gain = context.createGain();

var breath1 = context.createOscillator();

var breathGain1 = context.createGain();

knb1.type = "sine";

knb1Gain.gain.value = 0.1 / 8;
knb1.connect(knb1Gain);
knb1Gain.connect(context.destination);

breath1.connect(breathGain1);
breath1.type = "sine";
breath1.frequency.value = 0.01;
breathGain1.gain.value = (0.2 + 0.01) / 8;

knb1.start();

context.onstatechange = function () {
  console.log(context.state);
};

power.on("change", function (v) {
  v ? context.resume() : context.suspend();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nexusui@latest/dist/NexusUI.js"></script>
<div id="power"><div>  
<div id="dial"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my code was wrong.

`knb1.frequency.value = v;` is wrong!

correct line is `knb1.frequency.setValueAtTime(v, context.currentTime);`

changing this line solved my issue.

Comment: I think those two lines should be equivalent. If this fixed the problem then it's probably a bug in Safari.